# J2ObjC with source jar file

Tags: java, ios, xcode, j2objc

I need to translate itext source jar to objective c using J2ObjC.
I use the Xcode Build rules at [here](http://j2objc.org/docs/Xcode-Build-Rules.html) .
But when I add this script

```
"${J2OBJC_HOME}/j2objc" --build-closure -d ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR} -sourcepath "${PROJECT_DIR}/" --no-package-directories "${PROJECT_DIR}/Classes/Othello/Engine/itext-2.1.7-sources.jar" ${INPUT_FILE_PATH};
```

I get build errors[image]

[image]

This project was built and run successfully without my script.
Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last ${INPUT_FILE_PATH}. j2objc's flags are modeled after javac's (to support build tools), so any argument after the last flag is treated as a source file. Since the sources jar holds all the source files, the ${INPUT_FILE_PATH} tells the compiler to compile a directory, which it can't do.

Comment: I have changed to "${J2OBJC_HOME}/j2objc" --build-closure -d ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR} -sourcepath "${PROJECT_DIR}/" --no-package-directories "${PROJECT_DIR}/Classes/Othello/Engine/itext-2.1.7-sources.jar"; but build failed